# Decode/Unescape Unicode Entities in python

Tags: python, unicode, escaping, decode, entities

There are special characters in a string that comes with response, whatever I did, I could not make them look real.

```
"XMMdpyi92N2o%2fENOpJIS3fYRa1k%2bYHFccNSYo1IIkpk%2fMbVY3tlk2gCjgq1lU6KB"
```

I can get the real view when I decode this code with this site https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

Some special characters are available in response like `%2f` and `%2b` and these characters are represented by a list here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

All I want to do is to automatically decode these characters that come with response.

I am still learning python, I need experience from anyone who has knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are looking for [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote):

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.unquote("XMMdpyi92N2o%2fENOpJIS3fYRa1k%2bYHFccNSYo1IIkpk%2fMbVY3tlk2gCjgq1lU6KB")
'XMMdpyi92N2o/ENOpJIS3fYRa1k+YHFccNSYo1IIkpk/MbVY3tlk2gCjgq1lU6KB'
```